# How to include a file to my app

Tags: android

I want to play a alarm on my app so i need to know how to include it and to access

Answer (score 1):

You want to include the file as a resource. See [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Comment: thanks so now i have 
InputStream is = Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(R.raw.alarm); but how can i access the file with the media player?

Comment: You can create a media player instance with a reference to a resource id: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29

Answer (score 1):

put your media file (alarm.mp3) inside your res/raw folder.

```
   MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarm);
    mp.start();
```

Here´s the documentation [Audio and Video Playback](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/media/index.html)